# Binding properties in two viewmodels in a two way manner

Tags: silverlight, caliburn.micro

I'm starting Caliburn Micro development and I have thought of an architecture where a viewmodel has properties, injected by MEF, which are other viewmodels. That way I can use contentcontrols in the view to position them the way I want.

```
 public class ContactsProfileViewModel : Conductor<IContentItem>, IContactsModuleViewModel,      IModule, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    private string name;
    private string nameCaption;
    private ISingleLineTextContentItem firstName;
    private ISingleLineTextContentItem lastName;

    public ContactsProfileViewModel()
    {
        this.DisplayName = "Contact Tab";
    }


    public string Name
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
        }
    }
    public string NameCaption 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.nameCaption;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameCaption = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NameCaption);
        }
    }

    [Import(typeof(ISingleLineTextContentItem))]
    public ISingleLineTextContentItem FirstName
    {
        get { return this.firstName; }
        set 
        { 
            this.firstName = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
        }
    }

    [Import(typeof(ISingleLineTextContentItem))]
    public ISingleLineTextContentItem LastName
    {
        get { return this.lastName; }
        set
        {
            this.lastName = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LastName);
        }
    }
```

The viewmodel of SingleLineTextContentItem looks like this:

```
[Export(typeof(ISingleLineTextContentItem))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SingleLineTextContentItemViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, ISingleLineTextContentItem
{
    private string textBoxText;
    private string caption;

    public string TextBoxText
    {
        get { return textBoxText; }
        set 
        { 
            textBoxText = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TextBoxText);
        }
    }

    public string Caption
    {
        get { return caption; }
        set 
        {
            this.caption = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Caption);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need a way to bind the NameCaption property to the Caption property in a two-way manner. Is that possible? I'm I on the right track with this or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Roland

Comment: Which Caption are you refering to? You have 2 properties that have `ISingleLineTextContentItem` for first and last name so which one of these do you want to bind to?. Is is lastName.Caption or firstName.Caption or is it something else?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've set this demo up too quickly it appears :-) I want NameCaption to be bound to the Caption property of the ISingleLineTextContentItem FirstName.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is instead of having a backing field just route to the other view model

```
public string NameCaption 
{ 
    get
    {
        return FirstName.Caption;
    }
    set
    {
        FirstName.Caption = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NameCaption);
    }
}
```

However if the `Caption` property on the `ISingleLineTextContentItem` can get set independently then you need to register changes on the event and have the view model listen to changes. So instead you need somthing along the lines of:

```
public string NameCaption 
{ 
    get
    {
        return FirstName == null ? string.Empty : FirstName.Caption;
    }
    set
    {
        if(FirstName != null)
           FirstName.Caption = value;
    }
}

[Import(typeof(ISingleLineTextContentItem))]
public ISingleLineTextContentItem FirstName
{
    get { return this.firstName; }
    set 
    { 
        if(this.FirstName != null)
            this.FirstName.PropertyChanged -= FirstNameChanged;

        this.firstName = value;

        if(this.FirstName != null) 
           this.FirstName.PropertyChanged += FirstNameChanged;

        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NameCaption);
    }
}

private void FirstNameChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertName == "Caption")
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NameCaption);
}
```

Since either the `Caption` property or the `FirstName` property can change then we need to raise the event in the `FirstName` property and in the handler.